# Angular 5 setter over the @Input doesn't work

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

I have a project based on the Angular 5.
Lets say that I have the two components: `ParentComponent` and `ChildComponent`. `ChildComponent` has public setter with `@Input()` decorator. I give to it property from the parent component that will be changed later.

My problem is - this setter doesn't work with Maps, Interfaces, Objects like

```
{ [ key: string ]: boolean }
```

only with Arrays and primitives.

Well, it works, but only once.

I already understand that it's something with the data type but who can give a good explanation or link to the docs? Didn't find the allowed data types on the Angular web-site with docs.

What's wrong here?

Link to plunker if someone needs: https://plnkr.co/edit/WBS55F3wZSYI0qGNEGSd?p=preview

As you can see, there are 3 setters, they work in the first time, then only Array and String setters work. Why?

Update: Looks like it works if I change in the Map some value by its key that already exists, but doesn't work if I add new key=>value pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fields `mapItemsData` and `arrayItemsData` are both only set one time. The field `stringItemData` is set each time the object reference changes and this is because it is a string type and strings are immutable. The line `this.stringItem += this.iterationValue.toString();` actually creates a new string reference each time it is called which causes the child component's setter to be called again with the new value.

---

The reason you do not see the data being updated for `mapItemsData` is because you can't iterate it using `*ngFor` but if you add this to your template you can see that the same object is updated

```
{{mapItems.size}}
```

If you wanted to iterate the `Map` collection you can do that using [entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries).

```
<div *ngFor="let item of mapItems.entries()">{{ item }}</div>
```

For more information on the type [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) see the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

---

You also need to change your setting code so you do not point to a different (new) instance but point to the same instance that is being referenced in your parent (containing) component.

```
public set mapItemsData(set: Map<string, boolean>) {
    // this.mapItems = []; <- you were changing the reference here
    this.mapItems = set; // this is really all you need
}
```

---

[Updated plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/QC5pNNeqUIv37ZMnpXUp?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. One moment that still isn't clear for me - why setter function wasn't called in the ChildComponent? I understand that Map changed, I didn't saw these changes because I displayed the another array (I still need to do this array because in the real project it's a little more complicated). But why setted wasn't called? Just because of the "unsupported" data type that doesn't allow change detection on it?